# Will there be any current induced in a purely capacitive circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-circuits, inductance, electromagnetic-induction

Will current be induced in a purely capacitive circuit if a magnetic field B is present perpendicular to it and a movable conducting wire completing the circuit is moving with a velocity v.

Just want to know if any current will get induced if there is no resistance or impedance.

Thanks.

Comment: Moving the conductor will produce the emf. I cant see how thats related to the capacitor being present or not. Basically this reduces to the same capacitive circuit with an emf source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a conductor loop that includes a capacitor the changing magnetic flux will induce the same voltage as in the loop without capacitor or the same loop in free space without the conductor and capacitor.